# How to retrieve Id from the response which suddenly fails

Tags: groovy, microsoft-graph-api, scriptrunner-for-jira

We are using MS Graph api to collect Ad user information. One of our method suddenly stop working when using our groovy script.

Actually when calling the Graph API url from POSTMAN directly for requesting user information we receive the following response

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
"value": [
    {
        "businessPhones": [],
        "displayName": "Rhea Sam",
        "givenName": null,
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": "user@mydoamin.com",
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": null,
        "userPrincipalName": "user@mydoamin.com#EXT#@rlxcom.onmicrosoft.com",
        "id": "05906321-ed38-4bfd-9c9e-02bfb7d32405"
    }
]
```

}

Until now our groovy script call for that same API was working well but then suddenly stop working
Here is calling method code we are using

```
public String getGuestUserId(String AuthToken,String userEmail){

    String _userId
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?")

        http.request(GET) {

            requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
            //uri.query = [ $filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'"].toString()
            uri.query=[$filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'"]
           
            headers.'Authorization' = "Bearer " + AuthToken    

            response.success = { resp, json ->
                if (**json.value**){
                _userId=**json.value**[0].id    
                
                } 
                else
                _userId=-1 // user does not exist
                                    
            }

            // user ID not found : error 404
            response.'404' = { resp ->       
                _userId = 'Not Found'
            }

        }
        _userId
        
    }
```

What is happening when executing this method now is that the **json.value** return an error saying :
"No such property: value for class: java.lang.Object"

Note that if we try to return just the json.toString() then it return only

```
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
"value": []
```

What is wrong and how to solve it as it is suppose to return same information as the POSTMAN response in which we are concerned only to retrive the Id of teh user from the response

Thanks for your help
regards

Comment: could you pls try to comment this line `uri.query=[$filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'"]` and test again?

Comment: hello, I comment the line uir.query and it returns the ID of the first element.  in the json. So I guess the filter querry is not working properly anymore or has change. How to solve it ?

Comment: the query url should look like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'user@xx.onmicrosoft.com'`, could you pls debug your script and check the url you built?

Comment: Hello, how to return teh full url when executing ? I have try http.GetUri() but it does not return the query string part

Comment: sorry I don't know that....

Comment: seems trouble was coming from a groovy caching issue. Now it works again without doing anything special

Comment: that is fine it worked : )